# Prevent setInterval() from increasing speed after set number of clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I'm building a clicker game where I want a timer to auto click for me.  I want the timer to increase speed each time I click a button, but prevent increasing the timer's speed after clicking said button 5 times.

This is what I have come up with so far:

```
var total = 0;
var itemValue = 0;

var autoClick = function() {
    if(itemValue <= 5) {
        total = total + itemValue;
    }
};

$("#button").click(function() {
    itemValue++;
    setInterval(autoClick, 1000);
});
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: It's not increasing in speed. Every call to `setInterval` creates a new interval that calls `autoClick` once every second after it is created.

Comment: So, how do I prevent it from creating additional intervals after the 5 clicks?

Comment: Add an `if` statement to the `click` callback.

Comment: I've tried putting the setInterval() in between an if statement, but it still does the same thing.

Comment: I believe this is a scoping issue due to the anonymous function you're passing into the JQuery `click` call. I haven't tested this but feel like it's probably always using its own local itemValue rather than your global one. Try specifying that as an actual global function as well rather than anonymous and passing that in.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to increase `total` by x value each second.
x depending on how namy clicks on an "increase speed button"...
I got it?

To prevent concurring intervals, you have to clear the previous.

```js
var total = 0;
    var itemValue = 0;
    var myInterval;

    var autoClick = function() {
        total = total + itemValue;
        console.log(total);
    };

    $("#button").click(function() {
        if(itemValue <= 4) {
            // Increase...
            itemValue++;
            // Prevents multiple intervals.
            clearInterval(myInterval);
            myInterval = setInterval(autoClick, 1000/itemValue);
            console.log("Increasing by "+itemValue+" now...");
        }else{
            console.log("Hey! By "+itemValue+" is way enought!");
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button id="button">Increase speed!</button>
```

Comment: Very close, but I wan't the timer's speed to increase as well.

Comment: What is your timer here ? Is it the interval itself?

Comment: I edited... The interval delay shortens too now. Have a look.